# Sum by year and total_vehicles pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe **lrdata3** and I would like to sum the total_vehicles for every year instead of having multiple separate for the same year.

```html
year total_vehicles
0 2000 2016
1 2000 1483
2 2000 1275
3 2000 1086
4 2000 816
```

When I do this

```
lrdata3.groupby('year')['total_vehicles'].sum()
```

I get this which is not even a dataframe

```html
year
2000    419587299
2001    425832533
2002    430480581
2003    434270003
2004    442680113
2005    443366960
2006    452086899
2007    452280161
2008    445462026
2009    443333980
2010    438827716
2011    440461505
2012    440073277
2013    441751395
2014    451394270
2015    460050397
2016    470256985
2017    474693803
2018    473765568
```

Any help please?
Thanks

Comment: Your implementation seems fine to me. If the sum per year according to you is correct, you can do `df=df.reset_index()` to make it into a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, just add a `.reset_index()` to it. Like this:

```
lrdata3.groupby('year')['total_vehicles'].sum().reset_index()
```

This will get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line and get a df with this syntax.

Some sample data:

```
year    total_vehicles
0   2000    2016
1   2000    1483
2   2000    1275
3   2000    1086
4   2000    816
5   2001    2016
6   2001    1483
7   2001    1275
8   2002    1086
9   2002    816

df = pd.read_clipboard()

gb = df.groupby('year').agg({'total_vehicles': 'sum'})

print(gb)

    total_vehicles
year    
2000    6676
2001    4774
2002    1902

print(type(gb))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lrdata3.groupby('year')['total_vehicles'].sum().to_frame()
```

or [groupby and transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html)

```
lrdata3['yearlytotal_vehicles']=lrdata3.groupby('year')['total_vehicles'].transform('sum')
```